# kotlin Cursor.requery () is deprecated. What should I use?

Tags: kotlin

kotlin Cursor.requery () is deprecated. What should I use?

This method was deprecated in API level 15.
Don't use this. Just request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes back.

I'm using requery() in the following code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var db:SQLiteDatabase
lateinit var rs:Cursor
lateinit var adapter: SimpleCursorAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    var helper = MyHelper(applicationContext)
    db= helper.readableDatabase
    rs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 20",null)

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener {
        db.delete("TABLE","_id=?", arrayOf(rs.getString(0)))
        rs.requery() // ?????? 
    }
```

How should I fix rs.requery() sir
I don't quite understand, hope you can help me

Comment: It sounds like you've already linked to the suggestion for what you should do instead.  The answer to your question is "Just request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes back."

Comment: I just updated the code in my question, please help me fix it

Comment: I tried
rs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE",null)          
but it's not working, help me